# Search date that appears only table without content c#

Tags: c#, winforms, select, datetimepicker

this my interface application
[image]

if i search by date , Looks like this :

[image]

this my code :

> string a = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

```
        clsAccess db = new clsAccess(DB_PATH);
        string query = "";
        query = "select * from vwDataMHSSkripsi where Tgl_Sidang = " + a + "";
        DataTable dt = db.GetSummaryData(query);
        c1FlexGridPencarianSkripsi.DataSource = dt;
        db.CloseDatabaseConnection(); db = null;
```

I want to display the search results but which appear only tables without content

GetSummaryData looks like this:

```
public System.Data.DataTable GetSummaryData(string SQLStatement) 
{ 
    System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable(); 
    if (conn.State.ToString().Equals("Open")) 
    { 
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(SQLStatement, conn); 
        using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter rsAdapter = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter()) 
        { 
            rsAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd; 
            rsAdapter.Fill(dt); 
        } 
    }
    return dt;
}
```

Thanks...

Comment: did you try the query in your query window? what is your database

Comment: ya, I've tried it. access database.

Comment: I think single quote is missing, please try this query = "select * from vwDataMHSSkripsi where Tgl_Sidang = '" + a + "'";

Comment: hahahah i was try like that. error "Data type mismatch in criteria expression."

Comment: What class is your "db" object?  You have it as clsAccess but is this an ADODB connection or what?

Comment: Your code would be much better (and safer - please Google SQL Injection) if you used parameterised queries.  Thus it would be better if your GetSummaryData function accepted a List/array of DbParameters.  Are you using a generic class here, because you connect to different types of databases?  To give the best help here, it would be good if you posted the code for GetSummaryData

Comment: @JonathanWillcock clsAccess is connection for database

Comment: Please post GetSummaryData - then I'll have a much clearer idea

Comment: @JonathanWillcock this public System.Data.DataTable GetSummaryData(string SQLStatement)
    {
        System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();

        if (conn.State.ToString().Equals("Open"))
     {
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd = new
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(SQLStatement, conn);
            using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter rsAdapter = new 
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter())
            {
                rsAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
                rsAdapter.Fill(dt);
            }
     }

Comment: Check the date culture, may be your table is not showing date in the same database culture since date is reformatted, so when you have myDate = 'dd/MM/yyyy' is not parsed correctly because the database culture is MM/dd/yyyy since myDate = 'dd/MM/yyyy' will use default database culture to convert date, so, convert it manually using built-in function or use same date culture format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make everything much safer and easier, if you add a GetSummaryData function which accepts parameters.  The code for this should look something like:

```
public System.Data.DataTable GetSummaryData(string SQLStatement, 
    OleDbParameter[] parameters)
{
    System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(SQLStatement, conn);
        for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parameters[i]);
        }
        using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter rsAdapter = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter())
        {
            rsAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
            rsAdapter.Fill(dt);
        }
    }
    return dt;
}
```

You can now change the code that calls this in your example to:

```
string query = "";
query = "select * from vwDataMHSSkripsi where Tgl_Sidang = @mydate";
OleDbParameter[] parameters = new OleDbParameter[1];
OleDbParameter param = new OleDbParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@mydate";
param.OleDbType = OleDbType.Date;
param.Value = dateTimePicker1.Value;
parameters[0] = param;

DataTable dt = db.GetSummaryData(query, parameters);
```

Please note I have changed your check of conn.State.  Please use my one as it is much more efficient to use the correct value, rather than converting to string and then checking for "Open".

ADDENDUM

I deliberately allowed an array of parameters rather than just a single parameter, in case you need to call the same routine elsewhere with more than one parameter.  If using more than one, please be careful.  When using OleDb the order of parameters is important (and the names by contrast relatively irrelevant); you must add the parameters in the order in which they are referred to in the SQL string.

PS

What I should have pointed out, is that a corollary benefit of this approach, is that you do not need to worry about the format of dates.  The parameter takes as its Value a datetime (even though OleDBType is set to Date, this is in fact a datetime).  The library handles the interface to the database for you.